# Is is appropiate to use Mann Whitney's U to compare one group vs the others after a significant Kruskal Wallis AND significant post hoc tests?

Tags: wilcoxon-mann-whitney-test, kruskal-wallis-test

Ok, so I have a very basic knowledge of statistics and I'm trying to get my dissertation done  guided by books, internet tutorial and googling Q&A forums like this one.

I am comparing a satisfaction score between three different specialities of a profession in Jamovi: Speciality A, Speciality B and those that have both specialities, called group C. The scores are non-normally distributed, so I used Kruskal Wallis. I got a significant (<.001) test. I went ahead and did a Dwass-Steel-Critchlow-Flinger pairwise comparison (because that's the only post-hoc test Jamovi gives me) and speciality A is different from B and from C. No diferences between B and C, tho.

I then created a new transformed variable which separate participants between those with exclusevly Speciality A, and those with speciality B (alone, or with A). I run a Mann-Whitney and of course is significant, and I can get the rank biserial correlation. I understand the results better this way, but now I'm questioning if this was wrong.

Is this redundant? According to what I've read, Kruskal Wallis is sort of a repeated Mann-Whitney so maybe what I did is absurd and just giving the same information in two different ways.
If it is redundant, how do I express the absolute meaning of the differences between A vs everyone else? Like how do I report on this without using the Mann-Whitney analysis?

The kruskal wallis is giving me a H(2, 76)=14, p<.001 effect size 0.18. The pairwais comprisions are:
A-B: W 4.2, p .007
A-C W 5.1, p <.001.

The Mann Whitney is 92, p<.010, mean difference -7 and RBC = 0.72

Comment: Probably an answer:  It's useful to report the rank biserial coefficient for each of the pairs.  But --- if I understand correctly --- once you've conducted the KW test and the DSCF post-hoc, there's probably no reason to report the results of the additional Mann-Whitney test.  Unless you really wanted to compare A vs not-A in the first place.

Comment: This is not part of my main results, more like an acidental find, but it would be interesting for my discussion that *maybe* the speciality B is the cause of the difference, since those without it (Speciality A only)seem to have a lower score.

Comment: But isn't that what the post-hoc suggests ?  A is different from B and C ?